# How to change axis limits for time

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pandas

I have a data set stored in a Pandas dataframe object, and the first column of the dataframe is a `datetime` type, which looks like this:

```
0    2013-09-09 10:35:42.640000
1    2013-09-09 10:35:42.660000
2    2013-09-09 10:35:42.680000
3    2013-09-09 10:35:42.700000
```

In another column, I have another column called `eventno`, and that one looks like:

```
0     0
1     0
2     0
3     0
```

I am trying to create a scatter plot with Matplotlib, and once I have the scatter plot ready, I would like to change the range in the date axis (x-axis) to focus on certain times in the data. My problem is, I could not find a way to change the range the data will be plotted over in the x axis. I tried this below, but I get a `Not implemented for this type` error.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(13,7), dpi=200)
ax.set_xlim(['2013-09-09 10:35:00','2013-09-09 10:36:00'])
scatter(df2['datetime'][df.eventno<11],df2['eventno'][df.eventno<11])
```

If I comment out the `ax.set.xlim` line, I get the scatter plot, however with some default x axis range, not even matching my dates.

Do I have to tell matplotlib that my data is of datetime type, as well? If so, then how can I do it? Assuming this part is somehow accomplished, then how can I change the range of my data to be plotted?

Thanks!

PS: I tried uploading the picture, but I got a "Framing not allowed" error. Oh well... It just plots it from Jan 22 1970 to Jan 27 1970. No clue how it comes up with that :)

Comment: What is the ``dtype`` of your 'datetime' column? (if you evaluate ``df['datetime']``, it should give you that info)

Comment: If you put the `xlim` after `scatter` this works for me. So I also don't have the problem with plotting in 1970. What version of pandas are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting `ax.set_xlim` after the `scatter` command.

Comment: I was using `axes.plot` and I moved `set_xlim` after `plot` to fix this problem